# Emmet has stopped working in Visual Studio 2019 and VS code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019, emmet

I've been using VS Code to learn HTML for a few months.  I started with version 1.46.  Emmet was working fine from the beginning.  As soon as I upgraded to the new 1.47 version it stopped working.  I've reinstalled it several times and deleted all associated files but I still can't get it to work.  I even tried writing HTML in Visual Studio 2019 but it doesn't work there either.  I tried C++ code, too, but it's not working for that either.  Everything I've researched only talks about this:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": true,
"editor.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": "top",
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
```

all of which I have.  I've tried everything at

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

I don't know what else to try.  I'm using Windows 10.  Does anyone know how to fix this?